# How to find feedback edge set in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, kruskals-algorithm

Let G = (V,E) be an undirected graph. A set F ⊆ E of edges is called a
**feedback-edge set if every cycle of G has at least one edge in F.**

(a) Suppose that G is unweighted. Design an efficient algorithm to find a
minimum-size feedback-edge set.

(b) Suppose that G is a weighted undirected graph with positive edge weights.
Design an efficient algorithm to find a minimum-weight feedback-edge set.

---

My solution (need suggestions):

a) **Minimum size feedback edge set:** since the graph is unweighted, we can use DFS. We start DFS from any vertex as usual. When we encounter a back edge, we insert it into set of feedback edges. When DFS completes, the set will be the answer.

b) **Minimum weight feedback edge set:** since the graph is weighted, we can use Kruskal. But Kruskal normally starts with edge of smallest weight. If we can negate all edge weights, and then run Kruskal, whenever we get an edge between vertices of same component, we can save that in feedback edge set. In the end, negate edge weights. The reason I propose to negate edge weights is because we need minimum weight feedback set. With negated weights, Kruskal will start with edges with smallest weight (actually largest), and will find edges for same component with smaller weights.

Can someone tell if this solution is correct?

Comment: Wondering that in solution A, how do we account for the possibility of two cycles sharing an edge? Since that one edge will do job of two, surely that edge should be given priority over any other edge in either cycles.

Comment: @bytefire a diamond graph has 3 cycles, not 2. The min-size feedback edge set would be of 2, not 1. Picking or not picking the shared edge would make no difference.

Comment: there is actually a well know duality between these two problems c.f. graphic matroids and cographic matroids

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your solution is correct. Minimum-weight feedback edge sets of undirected graphs are complements of maximum-weight spanning forests. All spanning forests have the same cardinality, so in the unweighted case any spanning forest (as found by DFS) will do. (Proof sketch: matroids.)

Feedback *arc* set is indeed NP-hard, but this is the undirected case.

Comment: " Minimum-weight feedback edge sets of undirected graphs are complements of maximum-weight spanning forests." Can you explain this point a bit? Or post a link may be. It would be interesting to see the proof.

Answer (score 5):

To find a minimum-weight feedback edge set in a weighted digraph with positive weights:

By negating the weights, observe that it is equivalent to finding the maximum-weight feedback edge set.
To find a maximum-weight feedback edge set, build an MST using either Prim's or Kruskal's algorithm. Then take the complement of that MST.

Why does it work?
This is based on the following observation:

**An edge is not in any MST if and only if there exists a cycle for which that edge has the maximum weight over all other edges in that cycle.**
Or, in other words, an edge is in some MST if and only if for every cycle to which that edge belongs, it is not of maximum weight over all other edges in that cycle.

Indeed, assume we have a maximum-weight feedback edge set with an edge such that there exists a cycle comprising that edge and another edge with greater weight, then replacing that edge with this other edge would provide a feedback edge set of greater weight.

For completeness, a **proof** of the observation:

<=) Suppose an edge has the maximum weight in a cycle. If it were in some MST, then replacing that edge with another edge from that cycle would provide an MST with smaller weight.

=>) Suppose that for every cycle to which a given edge belongs, there exists an edge with greater weight in that cycle. If it is not in any MST, then adding that edge to an MST would cause a cycle in an MST. Then removing the edge of maximum weight from that cycle (which is different from the given edge) would provide an MST with smaller weight (and comprising that given edge).

Comment: Use `G'` to indicate the graph after negating weights. `G'`'s minimum spanning tree is `G`'s maximum spanning tree.

Answer (score 1):

Both problems are NP-complete. Therefore, even approximate efficient (polynomial-time) solutions are unlikely to exist (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set).

If you can relax the requirement for the strict minimum solution size in your application, there are other heuristics available, but they may be difficult to compare against each other.

Note that you can easily find minimal (not minimum) solutions: Go through the edges of any feedback edge set in any order, and remove immediately if redunant. One sweep over all edges is sufficient, and perform the redundancy test using, e.g., DFS.

Comment: Thanks @justkeepwalking for pointing out that this is the undirected case... thus my post misses the point of this question.

Comment: Minimum-weight feedback arc set is not NP hard, it can be solved with Kruskal algorithm by finding Maximum Spanning Tree. This can be done in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

For any feed-back edge, the complement of this graph must be a spanning forests of the original graph. This is to say that the complement graph doen't contain any cycle, which is very obvious.

Problem a):
For a minimum size feedback edge set, this is equivalent to find the maximum size spanning forests. So we can simply use DFS to find the spanning tree for each connected components of the graph and take the complement. Then we get a minimum size feedback edge. Actually, I think DFS is not necessary, as long as we can find for each connected components a spanning tree.
Problem b):
To find a minimum weighgt feedback edge set, this is equivalent to find the maximum weight spanning forests. Then we can use the Kruskal algorithm or Prim's algorithm to find the maximum spanning tree for each connected components. Then take the complement and we will get a minimum weight feedback set.

Answer (score -2):

Your solution A) won't work because you don't provide any logic to decide wether an edge has a "back" property or not.

Your solution B) won't work because Kruskal doesn't look for a feedback set, but for a min-weighted covering tree. A good example of why a min-weighted tree doesn't necessarily include a feedback edge set is the K4 graph.

Comment: As for answer to part A), DFS on an undirected graph classifies edges into tree edges and back edges - a very basic fact about DFS.

Comment: Nevermind, I answered too fast to this one.
You can indeed detect cycles using a DFS, when it meets a node that was already visited. However, how would you select which edge of that cycle will be part of your feedback-edge set ?
You could choose to use a DFS and to select any edge that leads to an already-visited node (and not only the edges pointing to an ancestor). This would for sure give you a feedback-edge set. But again, E is also a feedback-edge set.

Comment: What you're looking for is a minimum-size feedback-edge set. A good example of why DFS will fail to provide one with the logic is a graph made of two cycles with one single edge in common. There is no way for your DFS to tag only the one common edge with the logic you provided in your opening message, or with the logic I provided in the answer above. There are even cases in which this edge *won't* be part of the given solution. (sorry for making it two-part, not enough characters)

Comment: For the graph that consists of two cycles with a common edge, the common edge does not have to be part of the minimum feedback edge set. The reason is that this graph contains 3 cycles in total, and the common edge alone is no feedback edge set.